# Is it compulsory to have GPU and CUDA to run Keras/Autokeras in Windows 10? Can it run only on CPU?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gpu, auto-keras

I have tried to install keras, tensorflow, pytorch and all other dependencies in order to run a simple toy example using aukeras explained in https://autokeras.com/start/

After a lot of version changes and googling I found a typical error which prompts me to ask this question -

**ImportError: Could not find 'nvcuda.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Typically it is installed in 'C:\Windows\System32'. If it is not present, ensure that you have a CUDA-capable GPU with the correct driver installed.**

I don't have GPU or CUDA installed. Can I still run a toy example using CPU only?

Dependencies as mentioned below :
tensorboard          1.10.0
tensorflow           1.13.1
tensorflow-estimator 1.13.0
tensorflow-gpu       1.10.0
Keras                2.2.4
Keras-Applications   1.0.7
Keras-Preprocessing  1.0.9
autokeras            0.4.0
torch                1.0.1
torchvision          0.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall `tensorflow-gpu`, use only `tensorflow` if you don't have GPU.

The `tensorflow` is CPU only version, you don't need to install both of them but if you have both, it will choose the GPU version.

Maybe you need to reinstall the `tensorflow`, uninstall both of them and install only the CPU version might better.

`pip[3] uninstall tensorflow-gpu tensorflow`

`pip[3] install tensorflow`

Comment: Hi @Natthphon, thanks for a quick reply. I am still getting the same error after going through the uninstallation and installation process.

Comment: Do you have any GPU version left? Check it by `pip freeze`

Comment: No. Cleared everything related to GPU. I am trying installing one by one on fresh copy of python.